# output not displaying properly

Tags: java, android, xml

i am trying to make a healthcare app where user can book appointment of doctor read articles look at his booking buy medicines i have made half of the project but when i made buy medicine window code was right but the output was not shown only the price of medicine is shown not name and description of medicine[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfIlj.png  as shown in the last photo only the prices is seen not other details please help thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are some naming problems with your code. I suspect the reason why only the total cost is showing is because in SimpleAdapter, the name `"line 5"` matches the one you gave in the map.

Try feeding the key names you use in the hashmap to SimpleAdapter, e.g. changing the code in `new String[] {...}`.

Comment: list=new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<packages.length;i++)
        {
            item=new HashMap<String,String>();
            item.put("line1",packages[i][0]);
            item.put("line2",packages[i][1]);
            item.put("line3",packages[i][2]);
            item.put("line4",packages[i][3]);
            item.put("line5","Total Cost:"+packages[i][4]+"/-");
            list.add(item);
        }

Comment: sa=new SimpleAdapter(this,list,
                R.layout.multi_lines,
                new String[]{"line1","line2","line3","line4","line5"},
                new int[]{R.id.line_a,R.id.line_b,R.id.line_c,R.id.line_d,R.id.line_e}
        );

Comment: can you help to provide changes i am new to android